# Open SAS Program in new window

Tags: windows, sas

Currently when you double click on a SAS file in windows, it will open it in an existing SAS session you already have open. Is there a way to make it so that when it is clicked in windows a new SAS window would start?

Comment: You can have multiple sessions running at the same time.  It's not the workflow you are asking for exactly, but if you start SAS first (via Start->Program Files or wherever it is on your system), it will open a new session even if another is running.  Then drag the icon of the SAS program you want to run onto the new session window and it will open there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SAS is a so called "single instance" application so it's default behaviour is to open it in an existing session. In fact you may notice that it gets opened in the first session you have opened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, xiaodai. I do wonder if it is possible to change the default behaviour to a "multi instance" application so that new sas files are opened in a new window?

Comment: Nope. Actually I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for: [How can I change the default action when I double click on a SAS file in Windows Explorer?](http://www.sas.com/offices/europe/uk/support/sas-hints-tips/default_action.html)

Comment: Hi Louisa - this link is now dead (SAS have released an updated version of sas.com)