# Open SAS program in new instance

Tags: sas, ole

I'm trying to figure out a way to open SAS programs in new instances of the Enhanced Editor by default on click.

The question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654876/open-sas-program-in-new-window) before but no luck.

[This paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/115-2013.pdf) describes the way a program is opened with the Enhanced Editor. The full command is :

```
"C:\PROGRA~1\SASHome\SASFOU~1\9.3\core\sasexe\SASOACT.EXE" action=Open
datatype=SASFile filename="%1" progid=SAS.Application.903
```

The author explains that:

*The sasoact.exe program is used to launch an OLE automation session of SAS.
Automation
is a mechanism through
which one Windows application can control another application programmatically. When you double-click a SAS file
type, sasoact.exe checks to see if an existing OLE automation session of SAS is running. If not, it then invokes an
OLE automation session of SAS. Once there is an active
SAS automation server session, any further calls from
sasoact.exe are handled by the existing SAS session instead of in a new
SAS session.*

I guess having only one OLE session is usefull in some way or another but it's really annoying when you have to manually open a new EE instance every time you want to run multiple jobs. Not to mention that `sasoact` targets the first session initiated and if a job is already running on that session well your program is not going to open.

Is there a way to directly request a new instance of the OLE session or perhaps *"trick"* `sasoact.exe` into not seeing the opened sessions ?

**[EDIT]** *Well too bad it's been closed as duplicate because the answer is substantially different than the other question's. Also it might help others who do not want to run their programs from a batch file.*
Here is the registry key that works:

```
"C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)\sas.exe" -initstmt "dm 'whost;include ''%1'' ';"
```

I added it in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SAS.Program.701\shell\Open New\command` so now I have a neat little extra option in my drop-down menu that effectively opens programs in new sessions **on click**:

[image: More sessions!]

Comment: Check out Vasja's answer from the other time the question was asked - should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I missed that one. Will try asap. Danke

Comment: I'm hesitant to close as a dup unless it does actually work; running from cmd is very different from double clicking.

Comment: I'll see if I can add a registry entry pointing to the batch file and make it default, it'll be a convoluted solution but it might just do the trick.

Comment: Hi @Pane - if this has a solution... and your question gets re-opened. Can you please then post the solution as an answer? Also - you may at that stage want to point at the question that this is now marked as a duplicate of... these are clearly related, even if not exact duplicates.

Comment: @TarynEast answer is up, and I mentioned the other thread. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar thread showing the use of a batch file to open a SAS program in a new session is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323420/invoking-sas-9-2-to-edit-a-program-from-the-command-line-windows/19327692#19327692).

**If you want to open a .sas program in a new session by simply clicking the program here is how to do it:**

You have to add an entry to the registry. Be careful when messing around with registry files, always back up your entries.

Open the registry editor (WIN+R > regedit).
In the directory `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SAS.Program.701\shell\` create a sub-directory with a meaningful name(right-click on `shell` > New > Key). I named mine "Open New". In this new sub-directory create another sub named `command`. You should now have a path that looks like:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SAS.Program.701\shell\Open New\command`
In here, right-click on the file on the registry file on the right > Modify and add the following in the Value data field (change the path of sas.exe if needed)

```
"C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)\sas.exe" -NOTUTORIALDLG -initstmt "dm 'whost;include ''%1'' ';"
```

Close the editor. You should now have the new option specified in the drop-down menu of the right-click on a .sas program:

[image]

This option will open your program with the Enhanced Editor in a new SAS session.

Now if you want it to work for double-clicking I suppose you'd have to replace the value in the `Open` sub-directory with the one from above. I haven't done it and I don't recommend it, the extra option in the drop-down is enough for me.